# Setting contrasts for three way interaction using multcomp

Tags: r

I have a BACI experiment with measures before (2007) and after (2011) at three sites. Having trouble setting up the contrasts so I see whether the effect of year differs for treatments (cf the control) at each of the three sites.

I've tried to extend the example in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/vignettes/multcomp-examples.pdf) with no success. Have also tried the lsmeans package.

Example df and code below, as well as the explicit contrasts I'd like to test.

```
library(nlme)
library(multcomp)
require(lsmeans)

# I have these versions:
# R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
# nlme_3.1-126
# multcomp_1.4-4 



exdf <- expand.grid(Site = c("Z",  "Y", "X"), 
                   Plot = 1:30,
                   Year = c("2007", "2011"), 
                   Treatment = c("Control", "A", "B", "A+B"))
exdf$Site <- factor(exdf$Site)
exdf$Plot <- factor(exdf$Plot)
exdf$Year <- factor(exdf$Year)
exdf$Treatment <- factor(exdf$Treatment)
exdf$Treatment <- relevel(exdf$Treatment, ref = "Control")

exdf$Response <- rnorm(mean = 1150, sd = 130, n = nrow(exdf))

mod1 <- lme(data = exdf,
            fixed =  Response ~ Year * Treatment * Site,
            random = ~1|Plot)


## would like to test (obviously that's not actual code)

## How do the treatments A, B, A+B differ in their interaction with 
## year, compared to the control treatment (ie do the slopes differ)

SiteX:Year:TreatmentControl - SiteX:Year:TreatmentA == 0
SiteX:Year:TreatmentControl - SiteX:Year:TreatmentB == 0
SiteX:Year:TreatmentControl - SiteX:Year:TreatmentA+B == 0

SiteY:Year:TreatmentControl - SiteY:Year:TreatmentA == 0
SiteY:Year:TreatmentControl - SiteY:Year:TreatmentB == 0
SiteY:Year:TreatmentControl - SiteY:Year:TreatmentA+B == 0

SiteZ:Year:TreatmentControl - SiteZ:Year:TreatmentA == 0
SiteZ:Year:TreatmentControl - SiteZ:Year:TreatmentB == 0
SiteZ:Year:TreatmentControl - SiteZ:Year:TreatmentA+B == 0

## Also potentially - does the interaction between site and year
## differ across sites? 
SiteX:Year:TreatmentA - SiteY:Year:TreatmentA == 0
SiteZ:Year:TreatmentA - SiteY:Year:TreatmentA == 0
SiteZ:Year:TreatmentA - SiteX:Year:TreatmentA == 0

SiteX:Year:TreatmentB - SiteY:Year:TreatmentB == 0
SiteZ:Year:TreatmentB - SiteY:Year:TreatmentB == 0
SiteZ:Year:TreatmentB - SiteX:Year:TreatmentB == 0

SiteX:Year:TreatmentA+B - SiteY:Year:TreatmentA+B == 0
SiteZ:Year:TreatmentA+B - SiteY:Year:TreatmentA+B == 0
SiteZ:Year:TreatmentA+B - SiteX:Year:TreatmentA+B == 0


## Started doing the example from 
#https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/vignettes/multcomp-examples.pdf
# Got a bit stuck

tmp <- expand.grid(Year = levels(exdf$Year),
                   Treatment = levels(exdf$Treatment),
                   Site = levels(exdf$Site))
X <- model.matrix(~ Year * Treatment * Site, data = tmp)
glht(mod1, linfct = X)


## Gives all the interactions not in the form I want..
tt <- lsmeans(mod1, specs = ~Year:Treatment|Site)
comps <- pairs(tt, interaction = TRUE)
summary(comps,  adjust = "holm")
```

Comment: Regarding "not n the form I wasn't" for lsmeans - what form do you want? Seems like maybe you want something like ~Year|Treatment*Site, and maybe pairs() of that result?

Comment: Thanks. By 'form' I mean test the comparisons set out in the code. I tried your suggestion (which is similar to that at the end of my code) which doesn't test the comparisons above. A slightly different formulation, `ls <- lsmeans(mod1, specs = ~Year*Treatment|Site); pairs(tt, interaction = FALSE)` provides the right structure but is testing every combination of year and treatment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's build it up in steps. First, you want to get differences of the two years for each combination of the other factors. This is easily done in **lsmeans** using

```
tt = lsmeans(mod1, specs = ~ Year | Treatment:Site)
dd = pairs(tt, reverse = TRUE)   # (2011) - (2008) for each T*S comb
summary(dd, by = NULL)
```

You can now compare these differences as you like:

```
pairs(dd, by = "Site")
pairs(dd, by = "Treatment")
```

... or compare them marginally:

```
pairs(lsmeans(dd, "Treatment"))
pairs(lsmeans(dd, "Site"))
```